# Must be implicitly Convertible to System.IDisposable

Tags: c#

I got an error when I used using(MySqlBackup). I've already added the MySqlBackup.dll to its reference but I still got the same error. Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Here is the code:

```
public bool createBackup()
    {
        bool ret = false;
        using (var sfd = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
            sfd.Filter = "SQL Backup File (*.sql)|*.sql";
            sfd.FilterIndex = 1;
            sfd.FileName = "MyBackup.sql";

            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && sfd.FileName.Length > 0)
            {
                string file = sfd.FileName;

                using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connect()))
                {
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                    {
                        using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                cmd.Connection = con;
                                con.Open();
                                mb.ExportToFile(file);
                                con.Close();
                                ret = true;
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: So what's the error exactly?

Comment: what line does the code popup when you use the debugger and break points..? what is the exact error.. do you have the following references added to your project 
`Namespace:   System` in  your using section at the top of the cs file ||
`Assembly:  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)`
[MSDN IDisposable Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: When I paste your code into a new Console application and add the MySqlBackup.NET NuGet pacakge, the program compiles with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

`using` dispose the instance itself right after its scope ends. To do this, the class must implement the `System.IDisposable` interface.

If it does not, you can not use it in `using`, nor `Dispose()` of it manually. You will have to create its instance and let the `GarbageCollector` do this for you.

So, you have 2 options:

- Just implement `System.IDisposable` on your class
- Not use `using`

**With using:**

```
//inherit from "IDisposable"
class SystemResource : IDisposable
{
    //add Dispose method
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

**Without using:**

```
MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd);
try
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    mb.ExportToFile(file);
    con.Close();
    ret = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using "`using(//your class){}`" it has to implement `IDisposable`, then only it can support the `using(){} block`.
check [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/using) link for proper usage of this statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use MySqlBackup() with block coding , you only use the connection and command in this format (block) , but for this you will have to create its instance and dispose it manually.